# $@ becoming messed up

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a bash script that will examine the first argument, and if its one of particular values then it will remove that argument from the arguments and set some stuff up:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

echo args=$@

if [ "$1" == "valgrind" ]; then
    echo running under valgrind
    set $tool=valgrind
    shift 1
elif [ "$1" == "debug" ]; then
    echo running under gdb
    set $tool=gdb --args
    shift 1
else
    echo running normally
    set $tool=""
fi

echo tool=$tool
echo args=$@
```

However, When I run this it consumes all the arguments!  E.g.:

```
./my_script valgrind --something=y -r

+ echo args=valgrind --something=y -r
args=valgrind --something=y -r
+ '[' valgrind == valgrind ']'
+ echo running under valgrind
running under valgrind
+ set =valgrind
+ shift 1
+ echo tool=
tool=
+ echo args=
args=
```

and if the if-statements aren't followed:

```
./my_script valgrindx --something=y -r

+ echo args=valgrindx --something=y -r
args=valgrindx --something=y -r
+ '[' valgrindx == valgrind ']'
+ '[' valgrindx == debug ']'
+ echo running normally
running normally
+ set =
+ echo tool=
tool=
+ echo args==
args==
```

What is happening, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `set blah blah blah` actually sets the `$1 ... $N` parameters to whatever the arguments evaluate to, as shown in the following transcript:

```
pax$ echo $1

pax$ set $tool=hello ; echo $1
=hello

pax$ tool=xyzzy ; set $tool=hello ; echo $1
xyzzy=hello
```

(in that second command, `$tool` is not set which is why it comes out as blank).

In your case, `set $tool=valgrind` is setting `$1` to whatever the string `$tool=valgrind` evaluates to, which is why `$@` is changing. It is *not* setting the environment variable `tool` to `valgrind`.

If you want to set the variable, just use:

```
tool=valgrind
```

or, to make it available to subshells:

```
export tool=valgrind
```

The `set` command is used to either display environment stuff or set shell attributes and arguments, not named variables. If you have a look at the `man bash_builtins` manpage, you'll see the bit that explains this behaviour (search for the description of `set`):

> Any arguments remaining after the options are processed are treated as values for the positional parameters and are assigned, in order, to `$1, $2, ... $n`.

Answer (score 2):

```
set $tool=valgrind
```

should be

```
tool=valgrind
```

The set command is for something else in bash, try 'help set'.

Answer (score 0):

`set $tool=valgrind` should be just `tool=valgrind`. `set` has a different in Bash/Bourne-compatible shells than it has in the C shell.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the `getopts` too, for the `-x argument` handling. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260053/how-do-i-create-a-bash-script-that-accept-user-input-on-the-same-line-as-the-exec/6261949#6261949)